# binary search in a sorted 2d array using row / column pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, binary-search

I'm trying to build a function that uses binary search to find a number in a sorted 2d array and I'm given this function prototype that I can't change:

```
int findNum(int array[N][M], int num,unsigned int* row, unsigned int* col);
```

I tried this:

```
int findNum(int array[N][M], int num,unsigned int* row, unsigned int* col){
    int low = 0 , mid , high = N*M - 1;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        row = (mid / N);
        col = (mid % M);

        if (num < *(array + row + col)){
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (num > *(array + row + col)){
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
     
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently it's wrong because pointer plus pointer is not allowed (`*(array + row + col)`). I can't change the function prototype so I have to use the row / column pointers. I think it's also wrong how I used `row = (mid / N);` and `col = (mid % M);` because on one side they are pointers and the other just integers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How about `if (num > array[row][col])`?

Comment: But more importantly, are you sure that's how the array is sorted? It would help if you posted an example of an input array.

Comment: thats the problem, i could do that if row and col are integers but they are pointers and i cannot change that. and im given a sorted array of 5*5 of the numbers 1 to 25.

Comment: I see, then declare local variables like `int r, c;` and use `array[r][c]`. `row` and `col` are apparently output parameters. You should set `*row = something;` and `*col = something;` before returning from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row` and `col` look like pointers to integers that should be populated with the position of the value being searched for, given the function finds the value.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3
#define M 3

int findNum(int array[N][M], int num, unsigned int *row, unsigned int *col)
{
    unsigned int low = 0, mid, high = N * M - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        unsigned int r = (mid / N);
        unsigned int c = (mid % M);

        if (num < array[r][c]) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (num > array[r][c]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            if (row)
                *row = r;
            if (col)
                *col = c;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[N][M] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    unsigned int r, c;

    if (findNum(data, 4, &r, &c))
        printf("R: %u C: %u\n", r, c);
    else
        puts("Not found.");
}
```

Output:

```
R: 1 C: 0
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, made some changes.